# How can i get the logs of roles modifications on some specific IAM user in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, audit-logging

I need to know who modified(added or deleted) the roles for some specific IAM user in GCP. I could not get these details in GCP logging even after adding data write in audit logging for IAM permissions.
Are we missing something here?
[image]

Comment: @saurabh_umathe was my answer useful?

Comment: Thanks @GabrielRobledoAhumada, Though this command returning all the IAM details, I could tweak it to get the data I want.Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to query either your Cloud project, folder, billing account, or organization for audit logs.

Here you have an example of a query to a Cloud project and filtering just the logs where a particular user is involved:

```
gcloud logging read "logName : projects/$YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com AND \
protoPayload.response.bindings.members:user@domain.com" --project=$YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```

Take a look at the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging#gcloud) for more information.